# In Javascript how to convert 8,000,000 to 8 Million or 7,500,000 to 7.5 Million

Tags: javascript

I am getting a value from JSON as 8,000,000 but when i need to print it should be 8 Million or sometimes it will be like 8,500,000 and when i print the value in the page it should be like 8.5 Million using Javascript. Please can someone help.

Comment: Um. What? Do you mean you want to have natural language representations for large numbers?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is a good question. Why there are so many downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to divide by the unit you want, and manually append 'million' or 'thousand' (or whatever unit you're interested in).  There is no number to plain text translate.

ie

```
var foo = 4100000;
foo = foo / 1000000 + ' million';
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good solution

http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/2009/07/having-fun-with-jquery-numbers-to-words.html

Answer (score 0):

this will get you started

```
var number; //this is your number
var prettyNumber = "?"

var digits = new Number(number).toString().length;

if(digits>6) {
    number /= (10*6);
    prettyNumber = number + ' million';
} else {
    prettyNumber = new Number(number).toString();
}
```